# I do I create one row for each unique timestamp in this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

I have the following data frame in R that looks like this. Each depth and timestamp have a unique value. I can't figure out how to collapse the data frame to get rid of the NAs and have 1 row for each timestamp.

| time | depth1 | depth2 | depth3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | value | NA | NA |
| t1 | NA | value | NA |
| t1 | NA | NA | value |
| t2 | value | NA | NA |
| t2 | NA | value | NA |
| t2 | NA | NA | value |

I worked out a code that gave me unique depths for each row and unique timestamps for each column, resulting in a very wide data frame.

How can I reduce the rows to a single time stamp?
I need a dataframe that looks like this:

| time | d1 | d2 | d3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| t2 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| t3 | v1 | v2 | v3 |

I have tried a bunch of different things including
`spread(depth_ft, value)`
but have not had any luck.

The original data is like this:

| time | depth | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | d1 | v1 |
| t1 | d2 | v2 |
| t1 | d3 | v3 |
| t2 | d1 | v1 |
| t2 | d2 | v2 |
| t2 | d3 | v3 |

Comment: You could get the first non-NA value in each column by timestamp with `your_data |> summarize(across(everything(), \(x) first(na.omit(x))), .by = time)`, but it would probably be better to modify the code that created this data frame to do a better job. If you share the input from the previous step and the code you used we can help you improve it.

Comment: @GregorThomas I added some more information about the original data.

Comment: FYI, `spread()` is superseded now, now we can use `pivot_wider()`. But I think there might be something missing because `spread()` should have done what you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```r
tribble(
~time,  ~depth, ~value,
't1',   'd1',   'v1',
't1',   'd2',   'v2',
't1',   'd3',   'v3',
't2',   'd1',   'v1',
't2',   'd2',   'v2',
't2',   'd3',   'v3'
) |> pivot_wider(id_cols = time, names_from = depth, values_from = value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  time  d1    d2    d3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 t1    v1    v2    v3   
2 t2    v1    v2    v3
```